# How to pass data between pages with a normal link?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, query-string, http-get

I've recently learned the method of using `action="GET"` to pass form-data on to the next page.

I'm in a situation where I'd like to click a normal link (`a href=etc and so on`) and have it pass a little data on to the next page. Is that doable with just HTML and JavaScript?

Server-side is out of the question here, by the way.

Comment: I added the `Query-string` tag, because that's it's name... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and it's called `Query String` example:

```
<a href="www.google.com/?name=John">  click to search John</a>
```

`QueryString` on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)